# Stop framework from using HTTP Proxy

Tags: scala, playframework, wsdl, playframework-2.0, http-proxy

After nearly drowning in tears of frustration I have to ask you a question.

My play (2.0.3, scala) application is consuming a wsdl, which works perfectly fine, if I run the dev version of my webservice on **localhost**, which makes the wsdl-url something like `http://localhost:8080/Service/Service?wsdl`.
When I try to consume the WSDl from the remote test system server, with an Url like `http://testserver.company.net:8084/Service/Service?wsdl`, I get:

`[WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://testserver.company.net:8084/Service/Service?wsdl. It failed with: Got Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for URL: http://testserver.company.net:8084/Service/Service?wsdl while opening stream from http://testserver.company.net:8084/Service/Service?wsdl.]`

My company uses a http proxy for internet use, which is the reason for the 502 error. So I want play to stop using the proxy.

So far I have tried (all together):

- deleted proxy from Intenet Explorer
- set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dhttp.noProxyHosts="testserver.company.net"
- set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dhttp.noProxyHosts="testserver.company.net"
- play run -Dhttp.noProxyHosts="testserver.company.net"

None of this worked. Any ideas? How can I stop play from using the HttpProxy?

**EDIT:**

I found it has someting to do with java Webservices-api / jaxws libraries.
Any ideas?

**EDIT 2012-10-17:**

It seams to depend on system proxy settings. I still don't know why it didn't work that day although I deleted the whole proxy from IE and restarted everything. Is there any way to make my play app independend from system settings?

Comment: How are you consuming the WSDL?

Comment: I have a generated WSDL-Client as a jar, jaxb-api.jar, Specification-Version: 2.2, jaxws-api.jar, Specification-Version: 2.2, saaj, activation, ... as libs. I use this WSDL-Client to consume the wsdl.

Comment: Somehow we will need to figure out what the underlying HTTP request library is.  You might need to set some breakpoints to find that out.  But once you find that you should be able to find a way to configure it.

Comment: The underlying HTTP Transport is managed by JAX-WS Reference Implementation (Metro).  http://jax-ws.java.net/ The system settings can only be overwritten with setting system properties: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html I don't know how to do that in play.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
play -Dhttp.noProxyHosts="testserver.company.net" run
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a typo in your property, the correct property is `http.nonProxyHosts` so add and extra n after no.